Does the `File` Class have an equivalent of the `InvalidPathException` of the `Path` Class? Java
If a file-path that includes Illegal characters (such as ':' in a file-name) is passed into a Method of the Path Class—like Path my_path = Paths.get(/*invalid file-path as a String*/);—an InvalidPathException will need to be Thrown and Caught or else a crash occurs. Is there an equivalent Exception for the File class? i.e., does the File class also disallow Illegal characters in a file-path, or else does it allow them?

Possibly by calling the toPath method: see the class documentation. But it rather depends on what your code is actually doing.

The situation is ultimately determined by the underlying OS, so it would be completely pointless of either class to allow characters vetoed by the OS

What are you trying to obtain? If you want to create an old-fashioned File and have the exception, an option is to create the Path first and convert to File.

Files.createFile(path) will throw InvalidPathException if it contains unacceptable chars

On Windows at least, File will permit invalid characters and does not throw InvalidPathException unless you call toPath. Some examples:
Path.of("|")
=> Exception java.nio.file.InvalidPathException

new File("|")
=> OK

new File("|").getAbsolutePath()
=> resolves to same as 
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"|");

However path issue is detected if you try to use the File:
new File("|").createNewFile()
=> java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

new File("|").mkdir()
=> false, so it fails without reporting the issue

new File("|").getCanonicalFile()
=> Exception java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

